# PHP Laravel 5, global variables or constants from database

Tags: php, laravel, constants

I'm new to Laravel and wonder what the best approach is to use global variables or constants based on values within the database. Let's assume users can specify the site name, theme, admin email, default_image, language. These values are stored in the database and should be used across all controllers and views:

$config->admin_name = 'Administrator';

It could then be easily be used all controllers, views, etc by : $this->config->item('admin_name');

What is the best approach in Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this...

https://github.com/Grimthorr/laravel-user-settings

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers) come in handy here.